# How can I pull Data from an SQL table using PHP inside an HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I am building a website for myself (learning). I am trying to use .html for the base:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JPeG & Chaos LLP - Repair Status</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="menubar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="status.html">Repair Status</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<header>JPeG & Chaos LLP</header>

//XYZ

<p>
    blah blah blah blah
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Where I put the XYZ, I am wanting to pull a table from mysql and place it in to a table that updates every so many minutes (not concerned about the auto-refresh for now).

I tried adding the following PHP in to my HTML, but it doesn't act like PHP, it just prints the sql scripts :

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "name";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "RepairStatus";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT id, status, tip, eta FROM WorkOrders";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Status</th><th>Time In Progress</th><th>Est Time of Completion</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["status"]." ".$row["tip"]."</td><td>".$row["eta"]."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

the website  shows:

> num_rows > 0) { echo ""; // output data of each row while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { echo ""; } echo "

and continues through the remainder of the php section of the code.

I did run the full php code on a .php file through the website and it pulls the data just fine :

http://jpegchaos.com/rstatus.php

Any suggestions on how to do this so I can use my CSS / HTML to format the results?

Comment: when you place `php` code in `html` file it won't work php is server side and html is client side **so place your `html` code in `php` file**

Comment: That works a ton better! Thank you so much!

Comment: it works??? you get php output in html file??

Comment: I changed the tag to .php and it "works". I need to adjust it to function the way I want, but it's not spitting out SQL and PHP scripts anymore.

Comment: how you want to split function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run php within an .html extension file,
create .htaccess in your webroot with this line:

```
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

which instructs apache to process html file as a php file.

Also, try replacing these two lines, for shorter code

```
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
```

with this one:

```
    if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {
```